# My Netlify (React) frontend can't connect with my Heroku backend (postgresql). Locally it works fine

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js, netlify

For my application I connected my frontend hosted on Netlify to my backend on Heroku (Hobby Dev).
But for some reason they can't make a connection. Locally it works fine.

After my deployment to Heroku I installed the add-on [Heroku Postgres(https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) and heroku/nodejs building pack.
Am I missing something in my Heroku settings?

You can find my frontend code [here](https://github.com/rickhekman/stekjesruil-frontend) and my backend code [here](https://github.com/rickhekman/stekjesruil-backend).

My Procfile:

```
web: node index.js
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "stekjesruil-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "plant cuttings app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "7.6.x"
  }
}
```

My database.js:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const databaseUrl = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
const connection = new Sequelize(databaseUrl);

connection
  .sync({ force: false })
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to database!'))
  .catch(console.error)

module.exports = connection;
```

My index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')

const eventsRouter = require('./events/router')
const userRouter = require('./users/router')
const cuttingRouter = require('./cuttings/router')
const commentRouter = require('./comments/router')
const pastEventRouter = require('./events-photo-album/router')
const eventPhotoRouter = require('./events-photos/router')

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const app = express();

const corsMiddleware = cors()
app.use(corsMiddleware)

const parserMiddleware = express.json()
app.use(parserMiddleware)

app.use(eventsRouter)
app.use(userRouter)
app.use(cuttingRouter)
app.use(commentRouter)
app.use(pastEventRouter)
app.use(eventPhotoRouter)

app.listen(
  port,
  () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`)
);
```

Frontend connection, Axios.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
  // baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000'
  baseURL: 'https://stekjesruil-backend.herokuapp.com/'
});

export default instance
```

**I found the solution reading the heroku-postgres [connecting Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js) documentation: In the Heroku-CLI command line type:**

```
heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify
```

Comment: The backend seems correctly deployed and the frontend seems making petition at the correct URL, I tried to make a petition, but it gives me a `500 internal server error`, you can check the server logs in heroku and see what is happening.

Comment: Oh yeah it gives: ```ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "", user "", database "", SSL off.```

Comment: Did you add your `.env` variables into heroku?

Comment: I found the solution! You have to type in the heroku-cli: heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify

Answer (score 1):

For future generations. It works for me, when I add **sslmode=no-verify** to the connection string, like this

`postgres://username:password@host:5432/yourdbname?ssl=true`